# Usage of curly brackets at the end of function call kotlin

Tags: kotlin

What does it change between these two calls? I tried and they have the same behaviour

```
unsortedInputValues.joinToString(","){it}

unsortedInputValues.joinToString(",")
```

Comment: They indeed are the same. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's a ["trailing lambda"](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#passing-trailing-lambdas), a language feature inspired by Ruby's block syntax.